# Does "not use fan all the time" through BIOS reduces fan noise?

Tags: fan

I wonder if there is a way to reduce the noise of the fan. I read that through BIOS you can make it work only when it is necessary. What other options do I have to reduce the noise?

Comment: If your fan is in a Sony laptop of the "right" type, your best option is to [have the fan replaced under warranty](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/news-item.pl?news_id=299&mdl=VGNCS290J).

Comment: @DanH My laptop is HP Folio. I read on reviews that this is because of the manufacturer

Answer (score 2):

Options to reduce fan noise....

1. Replace fan.

Yes, it is true that some motherboards will include settings in the BIOS that will allow the system to monitor the temperature, and adjust the fan speed to attempt to keep the temp at acceptable levels.  Modern AMD processors include a [Cool & Quiet](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/cool-n-quiet/Pages/cool-n-quiet.aspx) feature that will work in combination with the right motherboard to not only slow the processor cooling fan down, but also underclock the processor to reduce heat generation.

Of course, without knowing the make and model of your motherboard, it's hard to say what settings might be included in your BIOS.

So, based on the available information you have provided, if you want to reduce fan noise, you should replace the fan with one that is quieter.

Answer (score 0):

Is the fan making a rattling noise? If so, then you would have to get it cleaned/oiled/replaced.

If the fan is simply noisy from spinning too fast, then your best option is to use a software program to monitor your system temperatures and adjust the speed of the fan as needed.

[SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) is a particularly good choice because it is quite customizable, and Alfredo Comparetti is constantly getting new spec-sheets from manufacturers to support new hardware.

One concern is that the BIOS may not be configured to allow for software to control the speed of the fans. In this case, you would have to enable the feature, or conversely disable the BIOS’ own auto–fan-speed feature. The [manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03177433.pdf) for your laptop mentions configuring the BIOS, but does not list the actual options. You would have to check it yourself for fan-related settings.